# remove multiple files between 2 files in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, delete

I have some files as below:

```
SRR797100.sra
SRR797101.sra
SRR797102.sra
SRR797103.sra
SRR797104.sra
SRR797105.sra
...
SRR797189.sra
SRR797190.sra
```

Now, I want to remove files between `SRR797101.sra` and `SRR797150.sra`, with just one command. I can do that by `rm` command file by file. Also I can provide a bash script for removing files. However none of them are my favourite solutions.

---

All files in one directory, because of many file names, I have censored SRR797106.sra to SRR797188.sra with "..." just for showing better.

I am using Ubuntu Gnu/Linux

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a shell such as `bash` you can use a construct like this

```
rm SRR797{102..149}.sra
```

I would suggest you test it with `echo` instead of `rm` first.

Comment: Thanks for you comment and solution.